# R: reducing glare with rgl package

Tags: r, rgl

I am using the rgl package to render a number of shapes, however I am running into the problem that the amount of reflectively/glare at different viewpoints can be distracting. I am sure there is some property that I need to change to cause the light sources to be ambient than directed. I have tried playing with following options:

```
clear3d(type = "lights")
rgl.light()
```

As well as

```
rgl.material(shininess=xx)
```

But I have not quite figured out how to change this property. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: A set of bordered cubes which reflect a lot of glare.]

Comment: can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: Did you try to set shininess to 100?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation (?material3d) is admittedly a bit obscure, but I think `lit=FALSE` will do what you want:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rnorm(5); y <- rnorm(5); z <- rnorm(5)
library("rgl")
plot3d(x,y,z,type="s",size=6,col="blue")
```

[image]

```
plot3d(x,y,z,type="s",size=6,col="blue",lit=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change the specular color:
    library(rgl)

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rnorm(5); y <- rnorm(5); z <- rnorm(5)

plot3d(x, y, z, type = 's', size = 6, col = 'blue', specular = 'white')
```

[image]